# 'BAD REQUEST' When calling API using Fetch method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, web

I'm trying to return some data from an API using the Fetch method, but I'm getting a 400 error. I'm probably missing something obvious, but I've been at this for so long I probably can't see the wood for the trees.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getJSON() {
    const API = 'https://API-URL-ENDPOINT';
    const QUERY = 'sample-query';
    const A_KEY = '{API Key}';
    const A_SEC = '{API Secret}';

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD);

    {/* Fetch Method Here */}
      fetch(API, {method: 'GET', headers: headers })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json));
      }

      function parseJSON(response) {
          return response.json()
          }
</script>
```

If anyone can offer any hints, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the docs for the Authorization header, you need to encode it in base64.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

So try `headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(  USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD ));`

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Typos can even sneak into Basic questions if you're in a hurry. ;)